# Show Ext Lib Value Picker Programmatically?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to find a way to open the Extension Library Value Picker automatically after load of my XPage. I tried putting the following in the onClientLoad event:

```
dojo.byId('#{id:MyValuePicker}').click();
```

But it appears that the value picker does not have a click() method to open the dialog. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Afaik it is a dijit. Try dijit.byId

Comment: @stwissel - I've tried dojo.byId and dijit.byId and neither seems to return the client side ID. I'm not sure if it would even help as I don't think the Value Picker control has a click() or open() method: http://goo.gl/KZWdC9

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed code based on @stwissel's comment and viewid issue:

Put the folloiwng in a scriptBlock:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    var viewID = "#{javascript:viewScope.viewID}";
    XSP.selectValue('extlib.dijit.PickerList',{
        "msep":",",
        "trim":true,
        "listWidth":"550px",
        "dlgTitle":"Select One Or More Values",
        "control":"#{id:BoundControl}",
        "url":"\/Database.nsf\/Test.xsp?$$viewid="+viewID+"&$$axtarget=#{id:MyValuePicker}"
    })
    ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

The viewID is set in the beforePageLoad event:

```
viewScope.viewID = com.ibm.xsp.application.UniqueViewIdManager.getUniqueViewId(facesContext.getViewRoot())
```

Comment: Replace axtarget=view:_id1:_id2:include1:MyValuePicker with axtarget=#{id:MyValuePicker}

Answer (score 0):

to get this working with bootstrap, use `extlib.dijit.BootstrapPickerList3`.
Or much better is 'extlib.responsive.dijit.xsp.bootstrap.PickerList'